# Como evitar que um while para execução antes de terminar a tarefa?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um problema ao fazer uma consulta em um banco de dados MySql. Essa consulta me retorna muitos dados, e estes dados são enviados para fazer uma comparação dentro de um `while`. Geralmente está excedendo o tempo do meu servidor terminando a execução antes de fazer todas a comparações.

Quero saber se tem um técnica para para comparar todos os registros sem que a execução seja interrompida?

É possível por uma barra de progressão ou uma porcentagem para saber quanto já foi processado?

Segue abaixo parte do código que estou usando para melhor entendimento.

```
 while($row=ibase_fetch_object($result)){

   $codigo = $row->CODIGO;
   $saldo  = $row->SALDO;

   $mysqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM especificacoes_do_produto WHERE edp_interno LIKE '$codigo'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($mysqlquery) != 0){
        mysql_query("UPDATE especificacoes_do_produto SET edp_estoque = '$saldo' WHERE edp_interno='$codigo'");
        $cad_texto = "Atualizado.....";
   } else { 
        $cad_texto = "cadastrar";
   }

 }
```

Comment: Acho que a sua pergunta seria: como definir o tempo limite de execução de um script em PHP?

Comment: Tem como mostar o código da consulta do firebird/inter base, talvez seja possível otimizar ela.

Comment: sim este é o sql que estou utilizando.. $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (itens.codigo), itens.codigofabricante, itens.descricao, itens.fabricante, itens.um, (select saldo from saldoiten(12,itens.codigo,null)) as saldo FROM itens itens, itensorcamentos io WHERE itens.CODIGO = io.ITEMESTOQUE and (itens.codigo BETWEEN '100000' AND '39999999') AND (io.DATAINCLUSAO Between '$date $hora_inicio' And '$date $hora_fim') AND (io.FILIAL=12) ORDER BY itens.codigo"; @rray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode definir o time out de um requisição use a função [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) passe zero como valor isso para deixar o tempo indeterminado. Adicione essa linha no início do seu código:

Pode fazer algumas 'otimizações' no seu código, se possível tirar o `like` já a pesquisa por código é exata e adicionar a clausula `limit` a consulta do mysql não está sendo usando em lugar nenhum serve apenas para contar os registros.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

while($row=ibase_fetch_object($result)){

   $codigo = $row->CODIGO;
   $saldo  = $row->SALDO;

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM especificacoes_do_produto WHERE edp_interno = $codigo LIMIT 1";
   $mysqlquery = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Consulta ficou muito grande e da este erro

Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:

XID: 338921723

Varnish cache server

@rray